# I can't show the creator of a comment in the view part

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am doing a facebook clone app and I am implementing comments in posts. I can show the comments from the post but when I try to put the name of the creator of the comment, it show me an error.

[The error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctVQN.png)

This is what I have right now.

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_09_02_233213) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "body"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "post_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "post_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_likes_on_post_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_likes_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.text "body", default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", default: "", null: false
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "posts"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
  add_foreign_key "likes", "posts"
  add_foreign_key "likes", "users"
  add_foreign_key "posts", "users"
end
```

users show views

```
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.body %><br>
    <%= form_for(post.comments.build, url: post_comments_path(post)) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
        <%= f.submit 'Comment' %><br>
    <% end %>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <%= comment.user.name %>
        <%= comment.body %><br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

users controllers

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @posts = @user.posts
    end
end
```

comment controllers

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        comment = post.comments.build(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))
        if comment.save
            redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        else
            flash[:error] = comment.errors.full_messages
            redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        end
    end

    def destroy

    end

    private

        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
        end
end
```

user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :posts

  has_many :likes

  has_many :comments
end
```

post model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :body, presence: true
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :likes

  has_many :comments
end
```

comment model

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :body, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a comment that is not attached to a user. This could just be test data that has been left hanging around but you should cater for this and only display the user if there is one

```
<%= comment.user.name %>
```

Could become

```
<%= comment.user.name unless comment.user.blank? %>
```

You should also cater for the occasion when a name is not present.

Anyway, if you add that fix you will be able to tell more easily which records are not what you expect them to be and sort them appropriately

Something like this might help

```
<% if comment.user %>
    <%= comment.user.name unless comment.user.name.blank? %>
<%else%>
  <p> The comment <%= comment.body %> has no user attached. Please fix this. The comment ID is: <%=comment.id%></p>
<%end%>
```

Code is untested so if you have a problem let me know
You can check for blank? if you prefer

***UPDATE***

```
<% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% if comment.user %>
    <%= comment.user.name %>
    <%= comment.body %><br>
  <%else%>
    No user for <%= comment.body %>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! that work, I just have to delete the else part. I don'y know why the else part render too, even when they show the username.

Comment: @NaguiHW, glad it helped

Comment: The else part should NOT show if you had a user? Are you sure this is happening? I think maybe it only looks like it's happening. I will update my answer to make it more clear

Comment: @NaguiHW I have updated my answer. Maybe that will help you to get a visual indication of what is happening

Comment: @NaguiHW It looks like in the first post the comment that is missing a user is a 3rd comment that is not showing

Comment: It's wierd. It keep showing the else part. Those are my tables and the rendered view https://imgur.com/a/TmjFbak

Comment: @NaguiHW see my updated answer, I was only dealing with the comments user name rather than the whole block. Sorry

Comment: @jamsec It's the same, I reset my db and it keep showing the else part. I don't know what's happening but that work for me, every comment is linked to an user, so I don't mind the else part. Thanks a lot!!!